# How to run jupyter notebooks on a remote server with job submissions?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hpc

I am trying to access some data from a simulation that I have run on a supercomputer that I have access to. I want to process it using a jupyter notebook, but don't want to download the data. Therefore, I want to run the jupyter notebook on the remote server and somehow access it from my local directory.

I am aware of the past solutions using port forwarding, but this does not work in my case (I've tried it!)

I think the reason for this is that I'm not actually running the jupyter notebook on the remote server. The remote server (say `me@remoteserver`) is just the node where I login. I then `qsub` a job submission script which runs on a different node.

Is there a way to access jupyter notebooks that I run using this job submission script?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe sharing more about how you tried it with `qsub` might make it easy to find the solution. I use `slurm` on my remote machine but I guess the steps should be the same.

You can first request a compute node with

```
## >> qsub -I -q shared -l nodes=1:ppn=1,walltime=2:00:00
```

then when you have resource allocated

```
## >> jupyter notebook --no-browser --port="port number" --ip='/bin/hostname'
```

Make sure to replace the port number and the hostname.

Copy the generated URL into your browser to become able to access the notebook.